# Is there an easy way to check library compatibility with Django versions?

Tags: django, compatibility, versioning

I have inherited a Django application that is currently on 1.4 (so no longer officially supported). I am working my way through the Django versions, upgrading the application and obviously many of the libraries used in the application are quite old versions as well.

Is there an easy / standard way to know what versions of a certain library will be compatible with specific Django releases?